# В этом предложении должна быть одна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

> Талант писателя позволяет сочетать и правду и фантастику и заставляет поверить в реальность событий.

Судя по моей книге для подготовки к ЕГЭ (под ред. *Цыбулько*), в этом предложении должна стоять **ОДНА** запятая. Это действительно так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В некоторых случаях при тесном смысловом единстве двух однородных членов с союзами И…И  запятая между ними не ставится, например: В шатре и тихо и темно. Были и лето и осень дождливы.

Вообще говоря, это во многом АВТОРСКОЕ решение, но в данном случае запятую лучше не ставить. Дело в том, что старшей структурой здесь являются однородные сказуемые, поэтому выделенная интонация перечисления для однородных дополнений вряд ли будет подходящей.

В то же время оба решения возможны.

Comment: Если бы запятая стояла, это бы выглядело так: "сочетать и правду, и фантастику и заставляет поверить"? Перед "и заставляет" запятой не нужно?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Vera, тут очень трудно усмотреть тесное смысловое единство. Так что все верно. Другое дело, что зрительно эта одна запятая выглядит вызывающе.

Comment: Что красиво, то и правильно. Обозначение "смыслового единства" используется в литературе часто, это во многом авторское решение. "В шатре и тихо и темно" - это же не синонимы/антонимы. Другое дело, что это не базовый школьный уровень, там лучше поставить запятую.

Answer (score 1):

> Судя по моей книге для подготовки к ЕГЭ (под ред. Цыбулько), в этом
>   предложении должна стоять ОДНА запятая. Это действительно так?

Я оснований для постановки запятой не вижу.